# Codeigniter - Session

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to realise authorisation library, but when I'm trying to get the userdata from the session. I'm getting nothing, and that's why the function check admin is not working.

Here is the code:

```
$CI->session->userdata('admin_logined');
```

but it return nothing. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the code you are working on

Comment: contact me via skype please samandarmir

Answer (score 0):

In your current code i hope you have created CI as instance.

Or you can use `$this->session->userdata('item')` to retrieve index(item)  data.

and `$this->session->all_userdata()` to get session all index data.

Also can check [codeigniter user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

try to  [auto load](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/autoloader.html) your session or initialize the Session class manually using

> $this->load->library('session');

Then you can use $this instead of $CI [check manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).Retrieve using

> $this->session->userdata('item');

Comment: i'm writing library) it doesn't work without CI =& get_instance

Comment: i cann add you in skype, i will provide the code please, give me ur skype name

Comment: This may help.Inside library try this $CI->load->library("session"); after $CI instantiation.Right now skype is not possible sorry

Comment: doen't work. but i have tried with $this in my controller. it's working) but i hava to do it with library